# Django model.py Many To Many Error Query clash

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to create my model.py with a many to many relationship between 2 tables as per the Django practice like follows:

```
class Options(models.Model):
    # Many to many relationship with Payment
    OPTIONS_CHOICES = (
        ('yearly', 'YEARLY'),
        ('bi-yearly', 'BI-YEARLY'),
        ('quarterly', 'QUARTERLY'),
        ('monthly', 'MONTHLY'),
        ('weekly', 'WEEKLY'),
        ('daily', 'DAILY'))
     can_be_paid_yearly = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=OPTIONS_CHOICES, default='yearly')
     payment = models.ManyToManyField('Payment', through='PaymentOptions')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.can_be_paid_yearly


class Payment(models.Model):
    # Many to many relationship with Options
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    deposit = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    options = models.ManyToManyField('Options', through='PaymentOptions')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.price, self.deposit


class PaymentOptions(models.Model):
    payment = models.ForeignKey('Payment', on_delete=models.SET)
    options = models.ForeignKey('Options', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This is the error I get:

```
ERROR:
rental.Options.payment: (fields.E303) Reverse query name for 'Options.payment' clashes with field name 'Payment.options'.
    HINT: Rename field 'Payment.options', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'Options.payment'.
rental.Payment.options: (fields.E303) Reverse query name for 'Payment.options' clashes with field name 'Options.payment'.
    HINT: Rename field 'Options.payment', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'Payment.options'.
```

How to fix this error and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't related model be addressed through app name? - `models.ManyToManyField('your_app_name.Payment', through='PaymentOptions')` and same for `Options`

Comment: @Charnel, actually I don't need to specify the name of the app as the model.py is in the app folder itself and mentioned on the url.py as app_name = 'app_name', however you were right for all the other part (I was putting the wrong table name, so Payment was supposed to be in Option and Options in Payment in the ManyToManyField line, please post the answer so that I can assign to you.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was flipping the callback from the ManyToManyField:

```
class Options(models.Model):
    # Many to many relationship with Payment
    OPTIONS_CHOICES = (
        ('yearly', 'YEARLY'),
        ('bi-yearly', 'BI-YEARLY'),
        ('quarterly', 'QUARTERLY'),
        ('monthly', 'MONTHLY'),
        ('weekly', 'WEEKLY'),
        ('daily', 'DAILY'))
    can_be_paid_yearly = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=OPTIONS_CHOICES, default='yearly')
    payment = models.ManyToManyField('Options', through='PaymentOptions')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.can_be_paid_yearly


class Payment(models.Model):
    # One to many relationship with Residential, Commercial
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    deposit = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    options = models.ManyToManyField('Payment', through='PaymentOptions')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.price, self.deposit


class PaymentOptions(models.Model):
    payment = models.ForeignKey('Payment', on_delete=models.SET)
    options = models.ForeignKey('Options', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```